# Locating a pop up window with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm building a program that login to a website and scrape some data. The login form is a pop up window. So I need to go to this www.betexplorer.com website, on the top right of the page there is a login link written "login". I click the link then the login pop up form appears. I'm able to locate the login link on top but I can't locate the pop up login form window.

I have used Selinium which works fine when applying the following code when dealing with JavaScript pop up.

```
String username = "myUsername"; WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("the xpath here")); 

String realUsername = "arguments[0].setAttribute('value','"+ username"')" ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(realUsername, element);
```

But I'm using HtmlUnit now and I've used it before and my other program works perfectly.

With HtmlUnit, I found a code that helps when dealing with JavaScript pop up. I'm trying WebWindowListener but I can't seem to figure it out.

Can anyone help?

My code snipets is below:

```
public class ExplorerHtmlUnit { 

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

WebClient webClient; 

webClient = new WebClient(); 

webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME); 

webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF); 

HtmlPage explorerPage = webClient.getPage("https://www.betexplorer.com");

System.out.println("Explorer Website Found"); 

List<DomElement> loginClick = 
explorerPage.getByXPath("//a[@class='clientmenu__item__in js-window-trigger'][contains(text(),'Login')]");

for (DomElement myele : loginClick) 
if(myele.getAttribute("class").equals("login")) { 

myele.click(); 
} 

} 

System.out.println("login link found and clicked"); 

//sleep for 5 seconds for javascript form to load 

Thread.sleep(5000); 

LinkedList<WebWindow> windows = new LinkedList<WebWindow>();

webClient.addWebWindowListener(new WebWindowListener() { 

public void webWindowOpened(WebWindowEvent event) { 

windows.add(event.getWebWindow()); 
} 

@Override 

public void webWindowClosed(WebWindowEvent arg0) { } 

@Override 

public void webWindowContentChanged(WebWindowEvent arg0) 
{ } 

}); 

WebWindow latestWindow = windows.getLast(); 

HtmlPage popUpPage = (HtmlPage) latestWindow.getEnclosedPage();

HtmlTextInput submitUsername = (HtmlTextInput) popUpPage.getByXPath("//input[@id='login_nick']");submitUsername.setValueAttribute("username"); 

System.out.println("UserName Found And Entered"); 

HtmlPasswordInput submitPassword = (HtmlPasswordInput) popUpPage.getByXPath("//input[@id='login_nick']");submitPassword.setValueAttribute("password"); 

System.out.println("Password Found And Entered"); 

HtmlButton loginButton = (HtmlButton) popUpPage.getByXPath("//html[1]/body[1]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[3]/button[1]");

loginButton.click();

System.out.println("Login Button Found And Clicked"); 

webClient.close(); 

} 

}
```

Comment: Try the Firefox driver (gecho) or the Chrome driver. Aparently HtmlUnit driver has some limitations, especially with javascript.
//Firefox
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverFname);
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
//Chrome
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverFname);
driver = new ChromeDriver()

Comment: @Redwine I tried Selinium but I prefer HtmlUnit. Thank you!

Comment: `myele.click()` opens the window? If so, you are adding the listener after clicking on element.